# How can I find all WebElements that contain part of a src?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my current code:

```
WebElement flyerContent = driver.findElement(By.className("wishabi-flyercontent"));
List<WebElement> pageItems = flyerContent.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://f.wishabi.net/flyers/611031/131463663056/3_0_1.jpg')]"));
```

The problem is that this only finds the one item. I would like to find all items that start with "http://f.wishabi.net/flyers" in src. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`starts-with()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with):

```
//img[starts-with(@src, 'http://f.wishabi.net/flyers')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As already answer is provided with starts-with(), we can use this one happily.. and also you can try with xpath what you tried by deleting that last dynamic numbers.. like below

```
List<WebElement> pageItems = flyerContent.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://f.wishabi.net/flyers/')]"));
```

Thank You